# AnyChart 'undefined is not an object' error occurs when touching the graph on a mobile device

Tags: anychart

When using a mobile device that is viewing an AnyChart graph, when you touch the graph 'undefined is not an object' error is thrown. This occurs on iOS. Anyone have ideas on what causes this and how to resolve the issue? I am using the latest release 8.9.0

I am using iOS 14.4.2 on a chrome browser, though the same occurs when using Safari.

Below is the base code for generating the chart:

```
this.chart = anychart.stock();

var credits = this.chart.credits();
credits.enabled(false);

this.plot = this.chart.plot(0);
this.plot.yScale().ticks().allowFractional(false);
this.plot.yScale().maximumGap(0);
this.plot.yScale().minimumGap(0);

let activeSeries = this.seriesTypeOptions.find(opt => opt.checked);
if (this.selectedRange === 'intra' && activeSeries.ohlc !== undefined) {
  activeSeries = this.seriesTypeOptions.find(opt => opt.value === 'area');
}
let data = activeSeries.ohlc ? this.ohlcMapping : this.valueMapping;
this.series = this.plot[activeSeries.value](data); 
this.series.name(this.longName + ' (' + this.symbol + ')');
if (this.mainColor && this.mainColor !== '') {
  this.series.stroke(this.mainColor);
  this.series.fill(this.mainColor, 0.5);
}

let grouping = this.chart.grouping();

grouping.maxVisiblePoints(700);

if (this.selectedRange !== 'intra') {
  switch (this.groupOptions) {
    case 'day': {
      grouping.levels([
        { unit: 'day', count: 1 },
      ]);
      grouping.forced(true);
      break;
    }
    case 'week': {
      grouping.levels([
        { unit: 'week', count: 1 },
      ]);
      grouping.forced(true);
      break;
    }
    case 'month': {
      grouping.levels([
        { unit: 'month', count: 1 },
      ]);
      grouping.forced(true);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      break;
    }
  }
}

this.plot.legend().titleFormat('');
this.plot.yAxis().labels().format("{%value}{decimalsCount:0, groupsSeparator:}");

this.plot.crosshair().yLabel().offsetX(-24);
this.plot.xAxis().labels(true);
this.plot.xAxis().minorLabels(true);
this.plot.xAxis().ticks(true);
this.plot.xAxis().minorTicks(true);

this.plot.yGrid().enabled(true);

if (!this.isIndex) {
  let volPlot = this.chart.plot(1);
  volPlot.legend().titleFormat('');
  let volumeSeries = volPlot.column(this.volumeMapping); 
  volumeSeries.name('Volume ' + ' (' + this.symbol + ')');
  volPlot.crosshair().yLabel().offsetX(-24);
  volPlot.height('25%'); 
  volPlot.xAxis().labels(false);
  volPlot.xAxis().minorLabels(false);
  volPlot.xAxis().ticks(false);
  volPlot.yGrid().enabled(true);

  if (this.mainColor && this.mainColor !== '') {
    volumeSeries.stroke(this.mainColor);
    volumeSeries.fill(this.mainColor, 0.5);
  }

  volPlot.yAxis().labels().format("{%value}{decimalsCount:1, scale: (1)(1000)(1000)(1000)|()(K)(M)(B)}");
  volPlot.enabled(this.isVolume);
}

//  add indicators
if (this.selectedRange !== 'intra') {
  let ind = this.indicatorOptions.filter(o => o.checked);
  ind.forEach(i => this.addIndicator(i.type));
}

var scroller = this.chart.scroller();
scroller.area(this.scrollMapping);
scroller.listen('scrollerchange', () => {
  let mv = this.chart.getSelectedRange();
  this.rangeStartDate = new Date(mv.firstVisible);
  this.rangeStopDate = new Date(mv.lastVisible);
});
scroller.enabled(this.isScroller);

let offSet: number = (this.isInfo) ? 425 : 275;
if (this.container !== undefined) {
  this.container.nativeElement.style.height = (window.innerHeight - offSet) + 'px';
  this.chart.container(this.container.nativeElement);
}

//  draw chart
this.chart.draw();
```

Comment: Please, can you provide 1) the chart code that reproduces the issue, 2) specify the iOS version, 3) the mobile browser you are using ?

Comment: I have updated my question as requested,

Comment: Thanks! We will try to reproduce the issue and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

If someone encounters the same issue.
Ignore the exception thrown by the chart on a mobile device. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to notify you that a new version of AnyChart library v8.11.0 is available.
Now the Stock chart doesn't throw errors on the user's tap.